# c++11 lambda expression issue (vs2012 update 1)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I have been fiddling around with lambda expressions to learn how they work but came across an issue. I have been trying to figure what I am doing wrong but can't seem to. The compiler just refuses to accept this simple example:

---

```
  int a = 2;
  std::vector<int> vv(10);
  vv[2]=2;
  std::count( vv.begin(), vv.end(), [&a](int z) { return a == z; } );
```

---

I get the error

---

```
Error   1   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found 
  which takes a left-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no 
  acceptable conversion) e:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
  11.0\vc\include\xutility 3243
```

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `count` takes a value to compare to. `count_if` takes the predicate....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithms need to know whether a predicate is based on comparing a value using equality or a unary predicate. To distinguish the two, a`_if` suffix is used for various algorithms: `find_if()`, `` `copy_if() ``, `count_if()`, etc. The lambda is OK but it isn't equality-comparable to the `value_type` of the sequence. You need to use `std::count_if()` when using a predicate:

```
std::count_if( vv.begin(), vv.end(), [&a](int z) { return a == z; } );
```

... or a value:

```
std::count( vv.begin(), vv.end(), a);
```